# Select except where different in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a bit of help with a SQL query.

Imagine I've got the following table

```
id  | date       | price  
1   | 1999-01-01 | 10      
2   | 1999-01-01 | 10    
3   | 2000-02-02 | 15   
4   | 2011-03-03 | 15     
5   | 2011-04-04 | 16
6   | 2011-04-04 | 20
7   | 2017-08-15 | 20
```

What I need is all dates where only one price is present.
In this example I need to get rid of row 5 and 6 (because there is two difference prices for the same date) and either 1 or 2(because they're duplicate).

How do I do that?

Comment: SQL server 2005 - I thought the tag would be enough...

Comment: I am confused about your requirements. They somewhat contradict themselves. You say you want only those rows that have a single price so you want to eliminate rows 5 and 6. But then you also state that you want to have either row 1 or row 2 returned. Which is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work with any DBMS

```
SELECT id, date, price
FROM   TheTable o
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT *
         FROM TheTable i
         WHERE i.date = o.date
           AND (
             i.price <> o.price
             OR (i.price = o.price AND i.id < o.id)
           ) 
        )
;
```

JohnHC answer is more readable and delivers the information the OP asked for ("[...] I need all the dates [...]").

My answer, though less readable at first, is more general (allows for more complexes tie-breaking criteria) and also is capable of returning the full row (with id and price, not just date).

Comment: This returns rows 1,3,4,6 and 7 - what I need is 1, 3, 4 and 7

Comment: @BlueEel you are right; I corrected that typo: is was `i.price > o.price`, but the correct is `i.price <> o.price`. Thansk for noticing it.

Comment: It is also using triangular joins which is pretty inefficient. Not sure what you mean about tie-breaking. There is no need for tie breaking here. If there are two values the same they shouldn't be returned. And to add the extra columns in an aggregate is super simple.

Comment: @SeanLange "[...] triangular joins is pretty inefficient [...]" I work with SQLServer more than 15 years now and I never felt such inefficiency. I understand you could be right, though; it is a case for checking performance on specific cases.

Comment: @SeanLange "[...] There is no need for tie breaking here [...]": sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I was relating to the "more general", that is, in other scenarios, not exactly the OP's one, where queries like this is applicable. Anyway, as the OP said "either 1 or 2" and my intention was to return the full row, my query has to decide how to break THAT tie.

Comment: @SeanLange "[...] to add the extra columns is an aggregate is super simple [...]": yes, but only using partitions. With the `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` syntax (the one JohnHC used in his answer) you would have to resort anonymous views (and also break the "either 1 or 2" tie).

Comment: You can read about triangular joins more here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you wanted a single value in JohnHC's answer you could simply add MIN(id), MIN(price). Never heard the term anonymous view...what is that?

Comment: @SeanLange you're right again. The `MIN` would work nicely. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

```
select date, 
       count(distinct price) as prices -- included to test
from MyTable
group by date
having count(distinct price) = 1 -- distinct for the duplicate pricing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE_1(ID ,DATE,PRICE)
AS
(
SELECT 1  , '1999-01-01',10      UNION ALL
SELECT 2  , '1999-01-01',10      UNION ALL
SELECT 3  , '2000-02-02',15      UNION ALL
SELECT 4  , '2011-03-03',15      UNION ALL
SELECT 5  , '2011-04-04',16      UNION ALL
SELECT 6  , '2011-04-04',20      UNION ALL
SELECT 7  , '2017-08-15',20     
)
,CTE2
AS
(
SELECT  A.* 
FROM CTE_1 A
INNER JOIN  
 CTE_1 B 
ON A.DATE=B.DATE AND A.PRICE!=B.PRICE
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_1 WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM CTE2)
```

Comment: @BlueEel Hi i just changed the code it gives result as expected and eliminates the records of 5,6